# Is there a IE tester for mac?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, testing

I want to test my site on different version of IE on mac, is there any software for that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try using an online browser tester, for example

- BrowserShots - http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score 27):

You can also use VirtualBox to install windows and use IE on mac . While virtualbox is free, you need to get a handle on windows OS.

- http://www.virtualbox.org/

You can also download the IE from Microsoft and use winebottler. It runs off of Wine and ‘bottles’ various Windows apps into launchable .app files that sit in your Applications folder like any other Mac app.

- http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

Comment: thanks for the Winebottler link, that's a new one on me.

Comment: There is also [`ievms`](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) project which tends to automate process of installing VirtualBox and virtual machines with official (IE Tester) images from Microsoft.

Comment: @Juicy Scripter Thank you very much man.

Comment: I'm using Winebottler, it is very good.   Thank you.

Comment: Combine this with https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Answer (score 8):

Use [Wine](http://winehq.org), a free OS X application that runs Windows executables. I use [Winebottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/), as it is a precompiled binary.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [browserling](http://browserling.com/) website. It's kind of slow, but it seems to be faster in the morning.

Comment: Who's morning? It's always morning somewhere.

Comment: My morning! haha I'm in the MDT zone. But this information has probably expired by now.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) which is a web service to check your websites against different web browsers running on different operating systems.

Comment: Not on the Mac there isn't :)

Comment: Oh! I did not notice that!. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Running a virtual machine with VirtualBox is the best way I have found to reliably test websites on multiple versions of Internet Explorer with Mac OS X:

http://blog.openviewpartners.com/internet-explorer-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

Check http://browserling.com/

Get an account and you can test many Windows browsers for free for 10 minutes at the time.