# CSS not rendering correctly in IE 8, 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have problem with http://abfoodpolicy.com/. In IE 8 and 9 the right sidebar renders about 300 px too far to the left. I work on a mac and I view the page in IE using Adobe Browserlab. I would LOVE to know how I can track this problem down. I'm not clear on where to begin since using something like Firebug hasn't proved helpful. Maybe I'm not using Firebug correctly to solve this problem.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: IEtester is not bad, although I'm not sure if it also runs on mac: http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing: `display: table` from `.abfp-content-layout` in your CSS

Also, if you're really serious about testing IE on a mac you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844713/1363726

Comment: I believe that did it. How did you track that down so quickly?

Comment: I've had issues with `display:table` before in IE so it was the first thing I turned off when going through it in developer mode.